# Sci-fi story about universe birth, heat death, and rebirth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I once read a story about a class of god-like beings who were learning to create universes.  Most of them created their universes to be just the "right" size, with enough mass that the universe would collapse in on itself, thus yielding an unending cycle of big bangs.  But the main character designed a universe that never stopped expanding (yielding a universe much like our own).

Ultimately, the main character's universe does devolve into heat death, but somehow achieves rebirth anyway.  (I don't remember the exact justification, but it seems reminiscent of [Penrose's Conformal Cyclic Cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology))

The story is at least two decades old (when I read it), but possibly older.

Does anyone know what the name/author of that story could be?  (I realize that isn't much info to go on.)

---

**Note:** I am **not** thinking of Asimov's *The Last Question*, despite the similar theme.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  I'm almost positive I've asked about this exact same story!  Check out https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/246046/101407 and see if it sounds like the story you're looking for.  (Note that even if it is likely the same story, having 2 questions open can increase the chance of getting an answer.)

Comment: Do you remember if you read it in a magazine (like *Analog* or *IASFM*) or in an anthology?

Comment: Hi ! I really appreciated your note. Of course, reading the beginning of your question I was about to answer : Asimov's *The Last Question*.  But I did read it to the end. This note deserved my upvote. Alas, I have no idea what the real answer is...

Comment: Asimov's wife J.O.Jeppson wrote something along these lines.

Comment: I've a feeling that I may have read it i Analog but haven't a clue as to when.

Comment: @DavidW Indeed, your post is about the same story!  To answer your question above, I know it was in a magazine.  I read the story at my then-girlfriend's house, which means it was sometime 2002-2004.  But I don't know if it was a *recent* issue at the time.  (The magazine belonged to her father.)

Comment: @MikeStone I'm almost certain I read this in Analog as well. Around 1990/1991. Analog was nearly  impossible to get here in The Netherlands, but the City Library in a town 20 kilometer away had all issues going back for many years. They didn't lend them out, but you could read them in the reading corner. I bicycled there every Saturday afternoon and spend a couple of hours reading them. Stopped doing that in 1991 because I got a weekend job. When I got back to that library in 1993 they had taken them out of the collection.

Comment: @Tonny Thanks for the tip. Okay, I looked at the [tables of contents](http://www.philsp.com/homeville/fmi/k/k00538.htm#A3) for the Analog 1990/1991 issues.  The only title that stands out (to me) is "A Question of Balance" by Kevin O'Donnell.  On the other hand, I guess you're saying that 1991 is the last possible publication date.  It could be older!

Comment: @superbatfish Yes. The Analog collection at the library went back at least 15 years. Last possible date would be late 1991. I started working weekends at a petrol-station in mid-February '92. As the Analog issues in the library typically took 10 weeks to arrive from the US, the most recent issue that I could possibly have seen on my last visit early February '92 would have been from November or maybe early December '91.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story is [Cycles](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48599) by Don Sakers in Analog, January 1985, pp 64-70.

It tells the story of a novice named Kaishyy who insists on creating his open universe without, according to his fellow students, sufficient mass-energy to become cyclic. He persists and waits for heat death, at which point the conditions became isomorphic with the starting conditions.

The first few lines are "At first, there was no space. How could there be?" They are echoed near the end, "In Kaishyy's universe, 10^250 years after creation, there was no space. How could there be?"

The Analog tagline is

> "Rules" for creativity tell how to produce results that will, almost certainly, be "acceptable." To do *exceptional* work, you may have to try something different!

I've been following these threads since I've been looking for the same story - I just happened across an old box of periodicals in my attic that I'd thought was long ago donated and immediately starting poring though them in search of this very story!